# Find an object based on substring value

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
const usecases =  [
    { usecaseId: 'Bill Gates', id: 1, description: 'CEO & founder, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Mark Zuckerberg', id: 2, description: 'CEO, Facebook' },
    { usecaseId: 'Steve Jobs', id: 3, description: 'CEO & co-founder, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Satya Nadella', id: 4, description: 'CEO, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Elon Musk', id: 5, description: 'CEO, Tesla & SpaceX' },
    { usecaseId: 'Ginni Rometty', id: 6, description: 'CEO, IBM' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Bezos', id: 7, description: 'CEO, Amazon' },
    { usecaseId: 'Larry Page', id: 8, description: 'CEO, Google' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jack Dorsey', id: 9, description: 'CEO, Twitter' },
    { usecaseId: 'Meg Whitman', id: 10, description: 'CEO, HP' },
    { usecaseId: 'Tim Cook', id: 11, description: 'CEO, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Weiner', id: 12, description: 'CEO, LinkedIn' },
  ]
  
 const str = "Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg, Tim Cook, Jeff Bezos, Steve Jobs";
 
 const newArr = usecases.filter(usecaseObj => {
    if(str.indexOf(usecaseObj.usecaseId) != -1) {
      return usecaseObj
    }
 });
 console.log(newArr)
```

I need to optimize the piece of solution to filter out the object based on string values, maybe using some ES6 feature.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to use `Set`:

```js
const usecases = [
    { usecaseId: 'Bill Gates', id: 1, description: 'CEO & founder, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Mark Zuckerberg', id: 2, description: 'CEO, Facebook' },
    { usecaseId: 'Steve Jobs', id: 3, description: 'CEO & co-founder, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Satya Nadella', id: 4, description: 'CEO, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Elon Musk', id: 5, description: 'CEO, Tesla & SpaceX' },
    { usecaseId: 'Ginni Rometty', id: 6, description: 'CEO, IBM' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Bezos', id: 7, description: 'CEO, Amazon' },
    { usecaseId: 'Larry Page', id: 8, description: 'CEO, Google' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jack Dorsey', id: 9, description: 'CEO, Twitter' },
    { usecaseId: 'Meg Whitman', id: 10, description: 'CEO, HP' },
    { usecaseId: 'Tim Cook', id: 11, description: 'CEO, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Weiner', id: 12, description: 'CEO, LinkedIn' },
];

const str = "Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg, Tim Cook, Jeff Bezos, Steve Jobs";

const set = new Set(str.split(/,\s+/));

const result = usecases.filter(usecase => set.has(usecase.usecaseId));

console.log(result);
```

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

    const usecases = Array.from({ length: 100000 }).reduce(arr => arr.push(...[
        { usecaseId: 'Bill Gates', id: 1, description: 'CEO & founder, Microsoft' },
        { usecaseId: 'Mark Zuckerberg', id: 2, description: 'CEO, Facebook' },
        { usecaseId: 'Steve Jobs', id: 3, description: 'CEO & co-founder, Apple' },
        { usecaseId: 'Satya Nadella', id: 4, description: 'CEO, Microsoft' },
        { usecaseId: 'Elon Musk', id: 5, description: 'CEO, Tesla & SpaceX' },
        { usecaseId: 'Ginni Rometty', id: 6, description: 'CEO, IBM' },
        { usecaseId: 'Jeff Bezos', id: 7, description: 'CEO, Amazon' },
        { usecaseId: 'Larry Page', id: 8, description: 'CEO, Google' },
        { usecaseId: 'Jack Dorsey', id: 9, description: 'CEO, Twitter' },
        { usecaseId: 'Meg Whitman', id: 10, description: 'CEO, HP' },
        { usecaseId: 'Tim Cook', id: 11, description: 'CEO, Apple' },
        { usecaseId: 'Jeff Weiner', id: 12, description: 'CEO, LinkedIn' },
    ]) && arr, []);

    const str = "Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg, Tim Cook, Jeff Bezos, Steve Jobs";

    // @benchmark Set

    const set = new Set(str.split(/,\s+/));

    usecases.filter(usecase => set.has(usecase.usecaseId));

    // @benchmark regex

    usecases.filter(usecaseObj => {
        return !!str.match(usecaseObj.usecaseId)
    });


</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am seeing as an answer:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, usecaseId: "Bill Gates", description: "CEO & founder, Microsoft" },
  { id: 2, usecaseId: "Mark Zuckerberg", description: "CEO, Facebook" },
  { id: 3, usecaseId: "Steve Jobs", description: "CEO & co-founder, Apple" },
  { id: 4, usecaseId: "Satya Nadella", description: "CEO, Microsoft" },
  { id: 5, usecaseId: "Elon Musk", description: "CEO, Tesla & SpaceX" },
  { id: 6, usecaseId: "Ginni Rometty", description: "CEO, IBM" },
  { id: 7, usecaseId: "Jeff Bezos", description: "CEO, Amazon" },
  { id: 8, usecaseId: "Larry Page", description: "CEO, Google" },
  { id: 9, usecaseId: "Jack Dorsey", description: "CEO, Twitter" },
  { id: 10, usecaseId: "Meg Whitman", description: "CEO, HP" },
  { id: 11, usecaseId: "Tim Cook", description: "CEO, Apple" },
  { id: 12, usecaseId: "Jeff Weiner", description: "CEO, LinkedIn" },
];

const str = "Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg, Tim Cook, Jeff Bezos, Steve Jobs";

const filterByKeywords = (data, keywords) => {
  const subStrings = new Set(keywords.split(", "));
  const result = data.filter((datum) => subStrings.has(datum.usecaseId));
  return result;
};

console.log(filterByKeywords(data, str));
```

Code above utilises ES6 function `has()` which is exclusive to `Set()`.
This can be modified further by replacing `Set()` with `Array()` and `.has()` with `.includes()` if only you're confident that keywords cannot contain repeated values.

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

```js
const usecases =  [
    { usecaseId: 'Bill Gates', id: 1, description: 'CEO & founder, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Mark Zuckerberg', id: 2, description: 'CEO, Facebook' },
    { usecaseId: 'Steve Jobs', id: 3, description: 'CEO & co-founder, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Satya Nadella', id: 4, description: 'CEO, Microsoft' },
    { usecaseId: 'Elon Musk', id: 5, description: 'CEO, Tesla & SpaceX' },
    { usecaseId: 'Ginni Rometty', id: 6, description: 'CEO, IBM' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Bezos', id: 7, description: 'CEO, Amazon' },
    { usecaseId: 'Larry Page', id: 8, description: 'CEO, Google' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jack Dorsey', id: 9, description: 'CEO, Twitter' },
    { usecaseId: 'Meg Whitman', id: 10, description: 'CEO, HP' },
    { usecaseId: 'Tim Cook', id: 11, description: 'CEO, Apple' },
    { usecaseId: 'Jeff Weiner', id: 12, description: 'CEO, LinkedIn' },
  ]
  
 const str = "Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg, Tim Cook, Jeff Bezos, Steve Jobs";

const newArr = usecases.filter(usecaseObj => {
    return !!str.match(usecaseObj.usecaseId)
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Why return !!str.match(usecaseObj.usecaseId) double exclamation? can't we use directly str.match(usecaseObj.usecaseId)

Comment: It is a double check !! converts the output to true or false